# Start Selenium test if input value==true

Tags: java, selenium

Here is a screenshot of my application:
[image: Screenshot of application]

I have a Boolean input which takes two values, *True* and *False*. Before the data is loaded, the input takes *False*, and after the data is loaded, the input takes *True*.

I want to start my test when this input equals *True*.

I am lost between the implicit and explicit fluent waits.

Here is the code I tried:

```
WebElement dataloaded

public String getDataLoaded(){
        dataLoaded=driver.findElement(By.id("dataLoaded"));
        return dataLoaded.getText();
    }
```

which I call here:

```
if(searchUser.getDataLoaded() == "true"){

    for (SearchCriteria searchWord : loadSearchCriteriaStepDfn.data) {

        searchUser.refresh();
        searchUser.Search(searchWord.getSearchCriteria());
        //TODO Replace 1000 value by an output from selenium
       // Thread.sleep(1000);
        softAssert.assertEquals(searchUser.count(),searchUser.Nbr_Of_raws());
        softAssert.assertEquals(searchUser.count(),searchWord.getCount());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It's helpful if you post the code you've tried

Comment: re-check the question  i add more detail and also the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem **could** be your String Comparison.

```
if(searchUser.getDataLoaded() == "true")
```

In Java you compare Strings with there `equals` method.
See https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_equals.asp

Try it with the following code:

```
if("true".equals(searchUser.getDataLoaded()))
```

FYI I put the String "true" in front to prevent Null Pointer Exceptions which could occur if your `getDataLoaded` should return a `null`.

Comment: This is the better, more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

`if(searchUser.getDataLoaded() == "true")`

with this

`if(searchUser.getDataLoaded().equals("true"))`